# How to get the previous route in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

My application needs to obtain the previous view on all redirects.  I currently have a parent controller that will check and grabs the current view.  This works fine.  How do I get previous?

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    String currentView = Request.RawUrl
    //Do stuff with currentView string

    //String previousView = ......?
    //Do stuff with previousView string


    var query = db.PageRoutes.Where(a => a.RouteKey == currentView).FirstOrDefault();
    if (query != null)
    {
         ViewBag.htmlRawData = query.Results;
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

On a final note, by using:

```
String previousUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
```

will bring back the previous page like //localhost:53188/Help/Index where as I just need /Help/Index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String previousUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath;
```

Comment: Keep I n mind that the `Request.UrlReferrer` will be null at the first visit and will also be null after e redirection.

Comment: Only first time UrlReferrer value is null, after that each redirections returns the absolute path as mentioned in the quetion(/Help/Index)