# Prevent the user from calling action method directly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 `View` like this:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
         return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Step2()
    {

         return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Step3()
    {
         return View();
    }
```

And 3 HttpPost Actions

```
    //Step 1
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Index(string number){}
    //Step 2
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Step2(string number){}
    //Step 3
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Step3(string number){}
```

For each `HttpPost Action Method` I  have created a `HTML Form` and I want that the user submits each form step by step (`step 1` -> `step 2` -> `step 3`)

Everything is OK but I do not want users can go to redirect `domain/controller/step2` or `domain/controller/step3`.
 I mean, user must follow my router `step 1` -> `step 2` -> `step3`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.net mvc How to prevent browser from calling an action method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407172/asp-net-mvc-how-to-prevent-browser-from-calling-an-action-method)

Comment: So, your question seems to be a matter of route priority. You'll find this thread useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25908768/4687359

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ways to solve your issue. One way to achieve this is by using `TempData` before your redirect command and check the `TempData` value in your `HttpGet Action Method`. For example for your Step 2 check you can do this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult Index(string number)
{
    //your business code 

    TempData["FirstStepDone"] = true;

    // return RedirectTo()
}

public ActionResult Step2()
{
    if (TempData["FirstStepDone"] == null)
        //return error

    return View();
}
```